# Creating custom animation functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to create a lightweight animation function to help stop me repeating code all over the place.  The code is simply an `animation({})` call with specific parameters so writing a plugin seems a bit overkill, so how can I create a custom jQuery function so that I can call it like `.slideUp` but without having to write an entire plugin to do it?

This is what my animation does

```
$("#id").css({opacity:0,"margin-top":"10px"})
    .animate({opacity:1,"margin-top":"0px"},'slow');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
  $.fn.slide = function(){
    $(this).css({opacity:0,"margin-top":"10px"}).animate({opacity:1,"margin-top":"0px"},'slow');
}

   $('#id').slide()
```